# How do I stop coiled (telephone) wire blocking signal?

Tags: ac, signal, radio, inductance, bypass

[image: Radio signal / circuit output being blocked by curly cord]

This circuit is working just fine if the output signal uses a straight wire, even if it is a very long wire with say a 1K resitor added to the end of it.

However, the signal does not get through when I use coiled (telephone handset) wire.

The only noticable result is that LED3 does not fully turn off (as it does with a straight output signal wire). Increasing the collector voltage and current to better push the output (by changing R1, R2, Rc & Re) only makes it glow a bit brighter.

The telephone wire carries 9V from a mains powerpack and GND via the main proccesing unit to this sub-circuit and returns the output signal back to the main processing unit.

I am perplexed as I have four other trigger circuits that work just fine through the coiled wire, including a very low signal PIR that needed the same "invert and amplify transistor block" to push it's signal through.

Presumably I have an issue with inductance or AC or something introduced by the 433Mhz radio link, but I don't want to give up on the convenience of coiled wire - so what do I need to change to get this working?

Probably the only thing I still have left to try is to replace this "invert and amplify block" with a Hex inverter.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, component values or other help.

Comment: Do you really have no base resistors for Q1 & Q2, or did they get lost in your simplification?

Comment: I suspect that the coiled telephone cord has a large reactance at 433MHz.

Comment: There are no base resistors on Q1 or Q2.  I tried a number of them including a 10K pot - there was no noticeable effect until there was insufficent current to turn the transistor on or off.

Comment: I have also tried a simpler setup by replacing Q1 with a PNP 2N2907 (to act as an inverting switch) and doing away with Q2 and its attendant resistors and capacitor.  That works just as well, but again only over a straight wire.  The curly cord stops the signal getting through, at least in sufficent stength to trigger a 555 receiving setup

Comment: The use of the PNP 2N2907 (as an inverting switch) setup is now working just fine over the shorter (30cm) length of culy wire.  There must have been a dodgy connection when I first tried this approach.

Comment: However, the longer (75cm) length still does not work – I think the cause is that too weak a signal fades away and too strong a signal going against the oncoming 9v in the curly wire creates a magnetic field that stops everything. 
I will an amplified setup tomorrow and start putting resistors on the output to see if we can just sneak the signal through.

Comment: Heh. It's the electronics equivalent of the "problem was caused by a typographical error" close reason on SO.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solution]
Cause of issue was the stereo socket developing an internal short.  I have also simplified the output part of the circuit and this is now working on even my longest (75cm) curly cord.

Thanks everyone who took a look.